# To partition or not to partition?

Tags: postgresql, performance, partitioning, postgresql-9.4

Having already read several questions on SO, external blog posts and manual

- [**SO**: Foreign Key constraint to partitioned table in Pg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822484/how-to-mimic-postgres-foreign-keys-into-a-partitioned-table)
- [**dba.SE**: Different ways of handling FK to partitioned table in Pg](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33605/38055)
- [**Manual**: Inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-inherit.html)
- [**Manual**: Partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-partitioning.html)
- [**Manual**: Constraint triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtrigger.html)
- [**Blog**: Postgres modelling with inheritance](http://ledgersmbdev.blogspot.com/2012/08/postgresql-or-modelling-part-3-table.html)

I still find myself wondering if I should go with partitioning considering my case or not.

### The case - simplified

Storing customer data. All names of tables mentioned below are made up for clarity.

1. Having objects that are identifiable by customer and are non-physical beings, also their physical objects in which they are actually stored in case of needing to send some objects back to the customer on demand, or process it in some other ways. They are mapped in a many-to-many relationship. `objects_nonphysical`, `objects_physical`, `objects_mapping_table`.
2. Second many-to-many relationship is between those non-physical objects and their metrics. There are objects which are bound with some metrics. `metrics`, `metrics_objects_nonphysical`
3. Both non-physical and physical objects have their hierarchy tables which are child-parent relations. `objects_nonphysical_hierarchy`, `objects_physical_hierarchy`

Depending on each customers' needs and requirements the data about **physical objects** can be supplied or might need to be created from scratch. Basically, what I need to do is:

- Maintain internal system for fast `INSERT` and `SELECT` statements, because here is where the mapping is going to take place.
- Maintain the system for external customer to view and operate on their **non-physical objects** - fast retrieval of data. **Strong need** of efficiency for `SELECT` statements - this data is available for many customers to search whenever they want.

### My consideration

There can be a customer, who may access the data, view and operate on it, but that doesn't need to be a contractor that we got the data from / are processing the data for.

This has lead me to introduce **table partitioning** into my system, considering that I always know which partition data should fall into (**partitioning for contractors**), and then to mainain system for external customer where I need **partitioning for customers** (this would be done with some delay using automation tools and set of rules to rewrite the data in customers manner, so that for each customer we'd only scan one partition for each table.

### Data volume

My data is going to grow constantly, especially when importing new customers' objects and metrics. The pace of new data arriving into the system is unpredictable at the moment for the long run. There is really no way to measure it not knowing who is going to be the next customer. Right now there are just 2 customers with more or less **1M** rows for every customer in every table. But in future I predict new customers to come with a volume of **10M** rows or so as well.

### Questions

These questions are all related to each other.

1. Should partitioning really be considered here, or is that an overkill? I consider it to be of use since I'm always scanning **exactly one** partition.
2. If partitioning is the way to go, how do I enforce `FK` constraint the most effectively considering my needs? Should I go for `constraint triggers`, or just keep it in the application layer for internal system, or maybe some other method?
3. If partitioning isn't the way to go, what should I dive into?

If there is not enough data supplied, please let me know in the comments below.

Comment: you consider partitioning for reducing future performance issues?

Comment: Basically, yes. I'd like to address the problem before it appears, because I have reasons to believe that it will come up. I'm in the phase of designing the system.

Comment: can you evaluate the size of this table in 1 year? 2 years? how much physical memory your server has ? cause to consider partitioning a rule of thumb is that the size of the table should exceed the physical memory of the database server.

Comment: As stated in the question, this is unpredictable. It may grow 5M rows in 2 years, but it may also grow 50M. Infrastructure remains unknown for now. We will evaluate and adjust, I imagine. Do you happen to have any reference for this rule of thumb?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html

Comment: In general it's recommended to start production without any overhead of indexes , partitions etc. then if necessary add indexes and partitions etc.

Comment: With partitioning, you are only going to get speed-ups on certain kinds of queries while taking a hit on other kinds of queries. You will also take a hit on writes. Partitioning shouldn't be the first thing you reach for, and I think you will be fine using plain indexes for the foreseeable future, and cross those bridges when you get to them. 5M rows isn't that large. This might be a useful blog with speed comparisons: http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/performance-testing-between-partitioned-and-non-partitioned-postgresql-tables-part-3/

Comment: @dizzystar I took the time to read those tests. Thank you for the link. Though, it seems like my approach would benefit a lot, since as I stated in my question, I'm going to look up __only in 1 table__, because I have simple equality partitioning, not range one. I'd say 50M rows have bigger chance to happen than 5M.

Comment: I agree with dizzystar, I wouldn't bother right now. Cross that bridge if you reach it. Currently partitioning in Postgres also makes it hard (if not impossible) to use proper foreign keys (this might change with 9.7 but nothing is settled yet). Even a table with 50M rows is not necessarily a candidate for partitioning. If you mainly have equality conditions in your queries that reduce the number of rows substantially, good indexing can get you a **long** way.

Comment: To me it is not really clear what you mean by 'partitioning for contractors'.  Are the tables that contractors use different from the ones that belong to a customer?  Does it ever happen that customer A has to access the data from customer B?  If not, then separating customer specific data into a per-customer schema might be a way to go - but not necessarily for performance,  but for separation of concerns (increased security/privacy and so on).

Answer (score 1):

There are many open ends in your question, but partitioning by customer could to be the way to go - especially if:

- you expect many customers,
- each of them could have tons of data ("tons" means much more than RAM cache size),
- most of their datasets will be mutually exclusive (each customer sees different subset of data).

RULEs or triggers are a performance overhead, and can be avoided.

Consider something along these lines:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE USER tenant1;
CREATE USER tenant2;

CREATE SCHEMA app;
CREATE SCHEMA tenant1;
CREATE SCHEMA tenant2;

CREATE TABLE app.objects_nonphysical(id int);
CREATE TABLE app.objects_physical(id int);
CREATE TABLE app.objects_mapping(id int);    
CREATE TABLE tenant1.objects_nonphysical() INHERITS(app.objects_nonphysical);
CREATE TABLE tenant1.objects_physical() INHERITS(app.objects_physical);
CREATE TABLE tenant1.objects_mapping() INHERITS(app.objects_mapping);
CREATE TABLE tenant2.objects_nonphysical() INHERITS(app.objects_nonphysical);
CREATE TABLE tenant2.objects_physical() INHERITS(app.objects_physical);
CREATE TABLE tenant2.objects_mapping() INHERITS(app.objects_mapping);

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA tenant1 TO tenant1;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA tenant2 TO tenant2;
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA tenant1 TO tenant1;
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA tenant2 TO tenant2;

/* TEST: simulate login as customer */
SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION tenant2;
/* No schema needed - default search_path works */
SELECT count(*) FROM objects_nonphysical; 

ROLLBACK;
```

You do not need any triggers / rules to maintain it.

There are open ends here - that's just a draft... Some issues:

- PK, FK and indexes are not "inherited".
- even if you create them, the PK is not enforced on master table
- you can overcome this by using same sequence for all tenants
- obviously, application must be adjusted for this model

Answer (score 0):

It won't hurt if you implement partitioning now, but use a single partition until your system really requires a new one. Performance-wise, there will be only a tiny overhead, to deal with primary keys and such.

I recommend using rules for redirecting inserts, and an external table for the primary keys (e.g. `CREATE TABLE objects_physical_ids (id bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)`, along with one function trigger that inserts a row in the ids table and copies it to NEW.id (e.g. `INSERT INTO objects_physical_ids DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING id INTO NEW.id;`), and other triggers that deal with deletion and updates, and a trigger executing those function triggers for each inherited table (do not forget to do this when you create a new inherited table!). Then all related tables can have a `FOREIGN KEY` to the relevant ids table (including any foreign key actions like `ON UPDATE` or `ON DELETE`).

Comment: The rules and triggers definitely have overhead, and it's easy to measure.  Additionally, they add complexity and make debugging (much) harder.  Also, after going down this way several times, I'd suggest (without admittedly knowing all the details) to keep an empty parent table and one or more child partitions.  When changing the partitioning scheme, this might come very handy.